# send DB mail with embedded image

Tags: html, sql, sql-server

I want to embed an image in my email body using HTML in the SQL server and I tried using  and it works for me but other recipients are not getting email with that image as an image stored in my local drive. how to overcome this problem and where should I store the image so that everybody in the email will get that?
below is my code
@sql=

Comment: If you can see the image (from your local drive) and others cannot then you're not embedding the image, you're only including an external reference to it like `<img src="file:///c|SomePath/SomeImage.jpg">`. To embed images in email properly you need MIME multipart/related messages whose HTML part references the image part(s) via `cid:` references to `Content-ID: ....` headers on each image part(s). Have a read through [RFC 2392 Content-ID and Message-ID Uniform Resource Locators](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2392)

Comment: Store the image on the server where sql server is installed.